# why does my external keyboard attached to my laptop does not work with power cable plugged in to laptop

Tags: keyboard

I have attached an external keyboard(USB) to my laptop dell inspiron 1525.

Problem is i am able to use the keyboard with the power cable unplugged ,
but as soon as the power cable is plugged in i am not able to use the keyboard.

Please suggest and let me know if you need some more information.

Comment: have you tried other usb ports while the power cord is attached?

Comment: yes, i tried just now after u told...:) but still the same problam

Comment: have you faulty or broken Cables either on the keyboard or the powercable? does the keyboard work after you plugged it in and made a rebook of the computer?

Comment: i made reboot twice but still the problem was there, but in the night i shut it down and when i used it in the morning it was working fine.Don't know what caused the problem anyway thanks everybody.